# td width fixed even if screen is too small

Tags: html, css, html-table

I don't know in advance how many `<td>` I will have. I just know that I want their width fixed even if the table gets too large for the screen.

For the moment, the following widths are ignored as soon as my table reach the right side of the screen.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="260" style="width: 260px;">Text only</td>
    <td width="260" style="width: 260px;">Text only</td>
    <td><img src="img/image.jpg" width="400"/></td>
    <td><img src="img/image.jpg" width="400"/></td>
    <td width="260" style="width: 260px;">Text only</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The issue is: `<td>` with `<img>` inside are 400px and it's just what I wanted, but `<td>`s with text only inside are downsized if the table gets wider than the screen.

My goal is to get the visitor scrolling from left to right instead of the usual up/down

edit: width of my IMG are not known in advance either. And strings are provided in HTML, so I would have to extract `width="400"`, I'd rather not

Comment: When you don't know beforehand how many td's you will have, then you must build the table so or so dynamically, means, javascript, php, C#, java, etc. When you do that you can simply count then the number of td's and calculate the overall width of the table.

Comment: I'm programming in PHP, but my issue is about HTML/CSS. For the moment I resolve it with Javascript, which is far from the best

Comment: finding the table width by programming is not impossible but I can't easily know in advance how large will be the image inside. The source is HTML, my customer send HTML text, like <img>

Comment: But then you can't make a fixed with of the td's, because every image could be bigger than the value you have used.

Comment: with img contents it goes well, my problem comes with text only content

Comment: That depends very much how your text is inserted in the cell. As paragraph, span, h1, without any tags,... When you use for example `<p>`s for the text then you can give a fixed width for the text-cells and the texts breaks at the end of the line. It then dynamically changes the height depending on the amount of content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this code:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td width="260"><span style="width: inherit; display: block;">Text only</span></td>
        <td width="260"><span style="width: inherit; display: block;">Text only</span></td>
        <td><img src="img/image.jpg" width="800"/></td>
        <td><img src="img/image.jpg" width="800"/></td>
        <td width="260"><span style="width: inherit; display: block;">Text only</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: unbelievable... can't thank you enough. I'll test it for a while but first tests went really well. If I don't post again it means it kept running well

Answer (score 0):

If you can come up with a reasonable maximum width for your table, you can wrap it in a div set to that width. This will allow the table to expand (the cells will be sized as you want them) and the page will show a horizontal scrollbar. The drawback is that if your table is much narrower than the max width, the page will scroll to the right beyond the end of the table.

```
<div style="width:5000px;">
  <table>...</table>
</div>
```

Comment: really? that is a solution you would use yourself?

Comment: no - I would not do the horizontal scrolling at all - but it is a possible sokution for the question - the accepted answer is a much better way to do it.